# How to use Virtualizer in a web aplication?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In my application i am using Jasper reports to generate the report in various formats. Now i am trying to generate a report for a huge resultset. When i went through the net, found that we can to use virtualizers in order to handle huge data.

I am using JRSwapFileVirtualizer, the problem is when is create the JRSwapfile it is throwing `File not found exception`.

I am providing the real path of the folder which i have created in the server, I am using WAS 6.0 server

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

**My Code**

```
JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile("http://localhost:9080/contextPath/reports", 2048, 1024);
JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(3,swapFile, true);
```

**The Exception**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost:9080\context-path\reports\swap_864564104_1316758806309 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the absolute contextPath from session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
ServletContextResource context = new ServletContextResource(context,"/reports");
```

Your code:

```
JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile(context.getFile().getAbsolutePath(), 2048, 1024);
```